# How to increase the font size of auto-generated R and p-value in ggscatter plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, font-size, pearson-correlation

I want to increase the font size of autogenerated r2 and p value. I used the code like
`+ theme(text = element_text(size = 18))` but it did not make any changes?

The code used are given below

```
# Load data
data("mtcars")
df <- mtcars
# Convert cyl as a grouping variable
df$cyl <- as.factor(df$cyl)


ggscatter(df, x = "wt", y = "mpg",
          add = "reg.line",                         
          conf.int = TRUE,                          
          color = "cyl", palette = "jco",           
          shape = "cyl"                     
          )+
  stat_cor(aes(color = cyl), label.x = 3) +
 theme(text = element_text(size = 18))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stat_cor` uses `geom_text`. The documentation in `help("geom_text")` tells you that it "understands" the `size` aesthetic.

```
library(ggpubr)

#recommended way
ggscatter(df, x = "wt", y = "mpg",
          add = "reg.line",                         
          conf.int = TRUE,                          
          color = "cyl", palette = "jco",           
          shape = "cyl",
          cor.coef = TRUE,
          cor.coeff.args = list(aes(color = cyl), label.x = 3),
          cor.coef.size = 12
)

#alternatively
ggscatter(df, x = "wt", y = "mpg",
          add = "reg.line",                         
          conf.int = TRUE,                          
          color = "cyl", palette = "jco",           
          shape = "cyl"                     
) +
  stat_cor(aes(color = cyl), label.x = 3, size = 12)
```

Comment: You know this, adding `+  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 0)))` will remove the a in front of the lines in the legend.

Answer (score 1):

`stat_cor` takes other arguments which pass pass to geom_text or geom_label, including "size" and "colour", so you can change your command like below

You can also try:

```
stat_cor( aes(label = paste(..rr.label.., ..p.label.., sep = "~`,`~")),
label.x = 0.5, method = "spearman",label.sep = "\n", size = 10)
```